# Retrieve Button value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

A simple one, I'm trying to retrieve the value attribute of a button when its been pressed using jQuery, here's what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.my_button').click(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>

<button class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="buttonValue">
    Button Label</button>
```

In Firefox my alert displays 'buttonValue' which is great but in IE7 it displays 'Button Label'.

What jQuery should I use to always get the button's value?  Or should I be using a different approach?

Many thanks.

ANSWER:
I'm now using

```
<input class="my_button" type="image" src="whatever.png" value="buttonValue" />
```

Comment: To help anyone else reading this, the 18-votes answer is the one written by @postpostmodern and edited by Nowaker :-)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I know this was posted a while ago, but in case anyone is searching for an answer and really wants to use a button element instead of an input element...

You *can not* use `.attr('value')` or `.val()` with a button in IE. IE reports both the .val() and .attr("value") as being the text label (content) of the button element instead of the actual value of the value attribute.

You can work around it by temporarily removing the button's label:

```
var getButtonValue = function($button) {
    var label = $button.text(); 
    $button.text('');
    var buttonValue = $button.val();
    $button.text(label);
    return buttonValue;
}
```

There are a few other quirks with buttons in IE. I have posted [a fix for the two most common issues here](http://gist.github.com/251287).

Comment: This question is the top google search result for 'jquery button value ie7', exactly what I needed to know and a great solution. Thanks

Comment: The `.val()` function in jQuery 1.6+ has a workaround for this bug and should now work as expected for IE6/7 (see [Ticket #1954](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1954)).

Answer (score 98):

As a button value is an attribute you need to use the .attr() method in jquery. This should do it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.my_button').click(function() {
            alert($(this).attr("value"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can also use attr to set attributes, more info [in the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr).

This only works in JQuery 1.6+. See postpostmodern's answer for older versions.

Comment: Thanks for that, IE7 is still returning 'Button Label' though.

Comment: IE7 is having difficutly with the fact you have text data inside the element. if you want to use an image you should use <input type="image" src="whatever.png" />

Comment: IE6 and IE7 (not IE8) seem to exhibit a bug related to <button> tags. The inner text of the tag overwrites the value attribute to almost all effects.

Comment: This does not work.  Using .val() or .attr('value') return the same incorrect thing in IE6/7

Comment: This no longer works for me in 2015. Now I have to do $(this).text().

Answer (score 17):

Button does not have a value attribute. To get the text of button try:

```
$('.my_button').click(function() {
     alert($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: That's not true. `button` *does* have a value attribute. https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.button.html#button.button

Comment: button does has a value attribute and you can update and fetch it with the help of juery val

Comment: though Button has a value attribute. But your solution worked for me. I think I just need the HTML text value inside the <button> and </button>. Then check the text using if conditions.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the new HTML5 custom data- attributes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my_button').click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('data-value'));
    });
});
</script>

<button class="my_button" name="buttonName" data-value="buttonValue">Button Label</button>
```

Answer (score 9):

Give the buttons a value attribute and then retrieve the values using this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  var value=$(this).attr("value");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

try this for your button:

```
<input type="button" class="my_button" name="buttonName" value="buttonValue" />
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm actually displaying an image in my button so it needs to be a <button>.

Comment: Ok, realised I can use and input as type="image" which works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by postpostmodern I have made this, to make .val() work throughout my javascript code:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    if($.browser.msie) {
        // Fixes a know issue, that buttons value is overwritten with the text

        // Someone with more jQuery experience can probably tell me
        // how not to polute jQuery.fn here:
        jQuery.fn._orig_val = jQuery.fn.val

        jQuery.fn.val = function(value) {
            var elem = $(this);
            var html
            if(elem.attr('type') == 'button') {
                // if button, hide button text while getting val()
                html = elem.html()
                elem.html('')
            }
            // Use original function
            var result = elem._orig_val(value);
            if(elem.attr('type') == 'button') {
                elem.html(html)
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
})
```

It does however, not solve the submit problem, solved by postpostmodern. Perhaps this could be included in postpostmodern's solution here: http://gist.github.com/251287

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the value attribute (buttonValue) then I'd use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.my_button').click(function() {
            alert($(this).attr('value'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: But it still does not work with IE7, see my work-around post below.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle();

    var x = $("#hide").text();

      if(x=="Hide"){
      $("button").html("show");

      }
     else 
     {
     $("button").html("Hide");

      }

       });

   });

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

 <p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

 <button id="hide">Hide</button>



 </body>
 </html>
```