# Using jQuery to Overcome IE Button Value Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

**Issue:** In IE 6 & 7, the text of a button element is returned in jQuery using .val() or .attr('value'), instead of the button's actual value. This is a known issue and it also occurs with straight Javascript using .value. There was a previous discussion on it here:

[Retrieve Button value with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487056/retrieve-button-value-with-jquery)

but an acceptable total solution was never found (only a hack where the button's text is temporarily hidden).

I have been working on a total solution so that whenever a button's value is accessed (be it on form submit or even just using jQuery/Javascript), the proper value is returned. I have it working with .val() with the below code. **I am seeking help with getting it to also work using .attr('value'), and even with straight Javascript .value if possible.**

I have set up a JSfiddle page where it can be seen in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hyperseer/RVyDN/2/

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $().iefixer();

});

(function($){  

    $.fn.iefixer = function(){  

            $.fn.origval = $.fn.val;
            $.fn.val = function(value){
                var elem = this[0];
                if(value === undefined){
                    var returnVal = null;
                    if( elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'button' )
                    {
                        returnVal = elem.getAttributeNode("value").nodeValue;
                    } else {
                        returnVal = $(elem).origval();
                    }
                    return returnVal;
                } else {
                    if( elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'button' )
                    {
                        elem.getAttributeNode("value").nodeValue = value;
                    } else {
                        $(elem).origval(value);
                    }

                }
            }

$('button').click( function() {

alert( "$(this).val() = " + $(this).val() ); // this works now with above fix
alert( "$(this).attr('value') = " + $(this).attr('value') ); // doesn't work
alert( "this.value = " + this.value ); // straight JS doesn't work

            });

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Your going to need to answer the question yourself or close it since this is now solved, its wasting peoples time reading it with the intention to answer it.

Comment: FYI, the `.val()` function in jQuery 1.6+ has a workaround for this bug and should now work as expected for IE6/7 (see [Ticket #1954](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1954)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I've now got it working with both the .val() and .attr('value') functions using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $().iefixer();
});

(function($){  

$.fn.iefixer = function(){  

    var ie = $.browser.msie;
    var ver = $.browser.version;

    if ( ie && ver<=7 ) {

        $.fn.origval = $.fn.val;
        $.fn.val = function(value){
            var elem = this[0];
            if(value === undefined){
                var returnVal = null;
                if( elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'button' )
                {
                    returnVal = elem.getAttributeNode("value").nodeValue;
                } else {
                    returnVal = $(elem).origval();
                }
                return returnVal;
            } else {
                if( elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'button' )
                {
                    elem.getAttributeNode("value").nodeValue = value;
                } else {
                    $(elem).origval(value);
                }

            }
        }

     var originalAttr = $.fn.attr;
        $.fn.attr = function(name, val) {
            if (this[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'button' && val === undefined) return $(this).val();
            return originalAttr.apply(this, arguments);    
        }

    }      

};

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

An improvement to Al. code, in order to make attr() function working with other value than 'value':

```
var originalAttr = $.fn.attr;
    $.fn.attr = function (name, val) {
      if (name === 'value' && this[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'button' && val === undefined) return $(this).val();
      return originalAttr.apply(this, arguments);
    }
```

for ie9 you need to check:

```
if (elem.getAttributeNode("value") != undefined) { // code };
```