# jQuery and PHP in while loop

Tags: php, jquery

My goal is to have a clickable link "view details" inside of the while loop listing all of the "pubs" that will bring up a popup modal that will display pub_details.php?id=x where x is the corresponding id number.

I need assistance on how to pass the id # to jquery, how to make it a "closeable popup modal", and to not have it open until i click "View Details".

Here is my header jQuery code that I am having some problems with..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "pub_details.php?id=",
    success: function(data){
    $("#content").html(data);
  }   
});

$("#content").dialog(
    {
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 100,
        modal: true
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

Here is my code from my index.php page

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_PUBS." WHERE status = 'Pending' OR status = 'Active' ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 5 ";
$result = $mysql->query($q);
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  echo $row->id;
  echo "<button id='content'>$row->id</button>";
}
```

Comment: Just a note about your html - running `<button id='content'>` in a loop, if more than one iteration, will result in multiple identical html `id='content'` attributes. You might want to make that `class='content'` instead, or use `id='content-{$row->id}'` to make them unique.

Comment: Michael, I updated that button to...
<input type="button" value="<?=$row->id?>" class="content"></input>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an id for that, use a class. Id's should be unique per page.

Comment: meaning in the <button class='$row->id'>$row->id</button>

Comment: <input type="button" value="$row->id" class="content">$row->id</input>

Then setup an on click event, $(".content").click(function() { ... }); , that does the ajax request and opens the dialog.

Comment: I had to make a <div id="content"></div> with the following jquery code.. When I add ?id=8 it brings be to a blank white page, how can I pass the class variable to it?
$(".content").click(function() { $("#content").load("pub_details.php?id=8");});

Comment: Made some updates and am almost there...

here is my jquery code..
$(".content").click(function() { $(".content").load('pub_details.php').dialog( { modal:true, width:600, height:400});  }); 

html
<input type="button" value="<?=$row->id?>" class="content"></input>

My problem is now that it is opening a modal for each of the id's in the while loop. and the modal window is just showing the id # instead of pub_details.php

also, how can I pass that variable id to pub_details.php?id=

Comment: You're going to need to perform an ajax request inside of the onClick and then on 'success' populate the div and open the dialog.

Comment: Ryan I'll paypal you $10 if you could fix up my code for this. let me know

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanrolds/RRmT6/

That should give you an idea what to do. You will to need run that on your server so that the ajax request comes back with a response.

Comment: The code does not seem to do anything for me. Even in jsfiddle when I click the buttons I am not getting a modal popup. Let me know if I am missing something or am I not doing something correct for this code to work

Comment: It wont work in jsfiddle as pub_details isn't accessible. You're going to have to troubleshoot what's happening with the AJAX request yourself, or provide a link to where this is hosted so I can look at the what happening.

Comment: http://mmapubs.com/test.php
http://mmapubs.com/test.phps
http://mmapubs.com/pub_details.php?id=5

Comment: I adjusted the fiddle, .html(data), try that. It looks like the result from the .html() call is bad. If it doesn't work with that change then it's possible it doesn't like having a whole webpage thrown in to the dialog.

Comment: somewhat success. Go to mmapubs.com/test.php

Comment: I think its working fine. Just checking. It looks like the initial page is changing, the modal works fine.

Thanks very much! will do some testing and let you know when I get it working successfully

Comment: Any idea why the buttons dissapear on the test.php?

Comment: It appears the whole page is being overwritten.

Comment: success! the reason the page was being overwritten was an error on the pub_details.php side.

Thank you very much for your help ryan, very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

See this question:
[Retrieve Button value with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487056/retrieve-button-value-with-jquery)

Just get the text from you button like this:

```
$(this).attr("value")
```

You may need to set the "value" attribute explicitly in your html.