# Using jquery to store button html in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically created button and would like to store the text and/or image in a variable.
The html that i need to store is everything between the two button tags

```
<button id="test">Update now</button>
```

So in this example i would need to store the text **Update now**.
Other examples have icon images between the button tags and text.

This would need to happen on document load.

Please could someone advise on how i can do this using jquery?

thanks

JC

Comment: maybe jquery.html? http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Do you want to read text of button with javascript?

Comment: I guess this question is very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487056/retrieve-button-value-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpDkX/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var buttonVar =   $( "button" ).html();
    alert(buttonVar);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var savedData = $("#test").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttonText = $('#test').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [reading the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/), but for reference purposes:

```
$(function(){
    var $buttonHtml = $('#test').html();
});
```

This would perform the function on document ready, as `$(function(){` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function()`. If you wanted to wait for all `img`s and CSS to finish loading, use this:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    var $buttonHtml = $('#test').html();
});
```

This waits for the entire window to finish loading before performing the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).on("ready", function () {
    var buttonHtml = jQuery("#test").html(); //Where buttonHtml is the variable that will contain your button html
});

//Later on...
console.log("This is the html from my button :" + buttonHtml);
```

Comment: As murat posted, .text() will be a better choice if you´re only retrieving text...

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need jQuery for that.

```
var buttonHTML = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Text:

`var text = $('#test').text();`

Image or text:

`var html = $('#test').html();`

Whatever you use would go inside:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/cw5e3/

HTML:

```
<button id="test">
<img class="selective"/>
</button>
```

JS:

```
var image=false;
var a= "Update now"
var imageVar="https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/q71/1157449_10151665223728870_898329738_n.jpg"

if(image){
    var imageObj = $('.selective', 'button');
    imageObj.attr('src', imageVar).show();

}else{
     $('button').text(a);   
}
```

CSS:

```
.selective{display:'none';}
```

Here I am assuming that you would know when its an image or a text.