# Yii and Javascript form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, yii

I'm using Yii as a PHP framework for my site. Additionally, my site uses some js/jquery like, say, a jQuery UI Dialog widget (except for those dialogs, the rest of the code is pure normal html form components and jQuery code for the event handlers).

In the Yii side, I use [CForms to build my forms from specifications file](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CForm).

When I test if the form was submitted, I must do it for a certain button. This is not only forced, but I also take advantage of it.

```
if ($myCFormInstance->submitted('approve')) {
    //process approval code
} else if ($myCFormInstance->submitted('reject')) {
    //process rejection code
}
```

The actual problem I have is a bit conceptual one, since -fortunately- I know what's going on with my code and -again, fortunately- know the problem root:

Somewhere in My code I intercept the submit button's click event:

```
$(function(){
    $(".critical-action").click(function(e){
        var form = $(this).closest("form");
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        confirmDialog("¿Continuar?", "#critical-action-dialog", function(){
            form.submit();
        });
    });
});
```

Say the .critical-action classed elements are always a submit button in a form.

The intention of the code: cancel the form submission, and perform it only if the user -in the dialog- clicks the "Yes, Continue" (i.e. confirming the action) button.

This code works as expected, and have no problems at a javascript level BUT -and here goes my issue- **when doing form.submit(), the button is not sent as part of the form**. This is obvious: I'm sending the form without specifying any button. In the case of Approve and Reject, which have two buttons, the example explains itself: if the `form.submit()` call could send their buttons ¿which of them should send?.

**Question**: So, since `form.submit()` doesn't send any button, but I actually **need** buttons ¿how can I send the form "with the corresponding button" -i.e. a button I choose to specify, which should correspond to `this` in the click handler function context- automatically via javascript? The button **NEEDS** to be identified by Yii in order to process the form (specially with the Approve and Reject case).

Comment: Maybe you can use a hidden input?

Comment: Perhaps it'd be a good idea. It was a fallback idea since i thought it'd exist a cleaner one. Please expand it as an answer, with an explanation and example for the community.

Comment: Maybe this could also be an issue from using `preventDefault` and `stopImmediatePropegation`.

Comment: No, the issue had nothing to do with them. I explained the issue: `form.submit()` doesn't send any button (I also explained why such behavior could be even harmful to my site) and I looked for a workaround to "add that button" by javascript (actually, without doing an ajax query). @kkhugs was right and I took his suggestion. I'm just waiting until he puts it as an answer since it worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added a hidden input to the form, you can modify the input value with jQuery before you submit the form, like this:

```
$("#inputID").val('approve');
```

If you want to set the value to the value of the clicked button via `$(this).val()`, be aware of the issue that could result in an IE browser, explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487056/retrieve-button-value-with-jquery). The second answer (by postpostmodern) has a solution to this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the warning :D however I don't need the `value` but only the name, fortunately. IE sucks anyway :(.