# php button value not getting passed to another php page via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass button value to PHP file2 but when I echo $_POST['view'], it returns undefined index:view.Any ideas?

PHP file1:

```
echo "<button method='post' class='btn view' name='view' data-toggle='modal' href='.myModal' value='$a' >View Images</button>";
```

PHP file2:

```
   include('db.php');
    session_start();
    echo $_POST['view'];
    die();
```

AJAX call:

```
$(".view").click(function () {
     $.ajax({
      url:"view.php",
      data:$(this).val(),
      type:"POST",
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if (data!=""){
          alert(data);
        }
      },
      error:function(data){
        alert("Network ERROR");
      }
    })
   return false;
 });
```

Comment: atleast you are learning to crawl. someday you will walk. then you will run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
data:$(this).val(),
```

to

```
data: {view:$(this).val()},
```

or

```
data: {view:$(this).attr("value")},
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/487105/689579

Comment: the problem persists..alert($(this).attr("value")) and alert($(this).val()) both provide the correct value

Comment: You need to add the key to your value -> `data: {**view**:$(this).attr("value")},`. Without the `view:`, your data is just sent as a value without a key, so `$_POST['view']` will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

in the Ajax call the line that reads

`data:$(this).val(),`

should be something like

`data:{view:$(this).val()},`

you aren't actually setting the "view" post variable.

Answer (score 0):

You define a value:

```
data:$(this).val()
```

But you never define a *key* for that value.  So the server-side code has no way of knowing that the value is called "view".  Give it a key:

```
data:{view: $(this).val()}
```