# get the value of clicked button using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to send the value of clicked button using ajax.

here's the buttons code:

```
<button id="accept" value="1">Accept</button> 
<button id="reject" value="1">Reject</button>
<br><button id="accept" value="2">Accept</button> 
<button id="reject" value="2">Reject</button>
<br><button id="accept" value="3">Accept</button> 
<button id="reject" value="3">Reject</button>
```

and the jquery code:

```
<script> 
var url = 'server.php';
$("#accept").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: 'post',
        data : {
            id : $("#accept").val(),
            action : 'accept',
        }
    });
});
$("#reject").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: 'post',
        data : {
            id : $("#reject").val(),
            action : 'reject'
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The 'id' sent in ajax should be the value of the pressed button.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IDs ***must*** be unique on document context, use class instead and and then inside handler, use `this.value`

Comment: unique id required. jquery won't know exactly which button you are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

**Please don't use duplicate** **id**. `id` should be unique.

And As a button value is an attribute you need to use the .attr() method in jquery. This should do it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.my_button').click(function() {
            alert($(this).attr("value"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with using  `$(this).val()` or better `this.value`

Comment: @A.Wolff `$(this).val()` does not work in case of  `button` i guess.

Comment: @A.Wolff It is not a `<input type="button"... `

Comment: `But i guess OP wants a $` Why that? And `value` is valid attribute for button element, it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/2qt3dr22/

Comment: @A.Wolff `.val()` does not work with a button in IE.

Comment: Which IE version? Seriously, did you test it before telling that it doesn't work on IE??? And please, don't tell me it doesn't work on IE4...

Comment: Yes, IE7, StackOverflow told me this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487056/retrieve-button-value-with-jquery

Comment: I'm unable to replicate issue even for IE7 emulated but seriously, do you really think OP needs to still support IE7?

Comment: @A.Wolff The way OP told me that he needs a `$`, The same way he must have told you that he does not want to support IE7 right? Why you so stucked with `$(this).val()`. What is the problem in `$(this).attr("value")` when it supports everything? I understand and aggree that `this.value` is better but why we discussing on `$(this).val()` when it has compatibility issues?

Comment: @A.Wolff The OP is a learner, I am also a learner but a pro like you should not show such behavior. You should guide us. And by chance if we know anything which you probably don't then please accept that.

Comment: Ok so `$(this).val()` doesn't work on old IE7 for labelized button element. I wasn't aware about it, so THX for the info! ;)