# Get value of the clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple buttons containing different values.

My buttons :-

```
<button id="1" name="1" value="1">Button1</button>
<button id="2" name="2" value="2">Button2</button>
```

Now, if I click on Button1, I should get it's value. That is **1**, and if I click Button2, I should get value **2**.
I have written this code :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("button").click(function() {
    var fired_button = $("button").val();
    alert(fired_button);
});
</script>
```

But it always alerts **1**. What must I do to fix my code?

Comment: use `$(this).val()`

Comment: you should look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487056/retrieve-button-value-with-jquery

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Use `this` instead of `button` in :

```
var fired_button = $("button").val();
```

You have to use `this` to target the current button clicked instead of `button` that will select all buttons in the DOM, .val() makes it to get the value of the first button.

---

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    var fired_button = $(this).val();
    alert(fired_button);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="1" name="1" value="1">Button1</button>
<button id="2" name="2" value="2">Button2</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something as simple as:

```
$(this).val();
```

```js
$(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
        var fired_button = $(this).val();
        alert(fired_button);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="1" name="1" value="1">Button1</button>
<button id="2" name="2" value="2">Button2</button>
```

Note: you should add your event listeners after the document is ready. This is why, I have enclosed the event handler in the

```
$(function{})
```

This is a shorthand of

```
$(document).ready(function(){})
```

For more information about this, please have a look [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `this` variable in order to access the clicked button's value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("button").click(function() {
    var fired_button = $(this).val();
    alert(fired_button);
});
</script>
```

This would return the `value` of the button.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` inside the click handler

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("button").click(function() {
    var fired_button = $(this).val();
    alert(fired_button);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` will give you the element that was clicked, `$(this)` to get a jquery version.

Update your code to:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var fired_button = $(this).val();
    alert(fired_button);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `$(this).val();`. It will return clicked button value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you're looking for the .attr() function.

```
$(this).attr("value")
```

That code will give you the value attribute of the html element designed by $(this) (or you precise the ID of the element).

Answer (score 1):

Plain JavaScript solution with ES6 syntax:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const fired_button = button.value;
        alert(fired_button);
        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(this).val()`.
'this' always refers to the current object.

Answer (score 0):

this will give you the element that was clicked, `$(this)` to get a jquery version.

Update your code to:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var fired_button = $(this).val();
    alert(fired_button);
});
```