# jquery not appending text to texarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [smiley](https://github.com/DrevanTonder/smiley) and [uikit](http://getuikit.com/index.html) to make an emoticon insert for a texarea.

html:

```
<textarea class="smiley-input uk-width-1-1"></textarea>
  <button type="button" class="smiley-button uk-float-right">
    &#128513
  </button>
  <div class="smiley-picker hidden uk-float-right"></div>
```

javascript:

```
$(".smiley-button").click(function() {
  if ($(".smiley-picker").hasClass("hidden")) {
    $(".smiley-picker").fadeIn("fast");
    $(".smiley-picker").toggleClass("hidden");
  } else {
    $(".smiley-picker").fadeOut("fast");
    $(".smiley-picker").toggleClass("hidden");
  }
});
for (i = 128512; i < 128576; i++) {
    $(".smiley-picker").append("<button type='button' class='smiley'>&#"+i+"</button>");
}
for (i = 128581; i < 128591; i++) {
    $(".smiley-picker").append("<button type='button' class='smiley'>&#"+i+"</button>");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click",".smiley",function(){
    $(".smiley-input").val($('.smiley-input').val()+$(this).text());
  });
});
```

For some reason it does not add an emoticon to the `textarea`.
**UPDATE:**
 had to add `value='&#"+i+"'` in `smiley` buttons.

Comment: Your code working properly.

Comment: seems to be working on chrome https://jsfiddle.net/oz6kzoj6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Firefox works differently to Edge and IE [Retrieve Button value with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487056/retrieve-button-value-with-jquery)
I had to add `value='&#"+i+"'` in the button so that it looks like this:

```
for (i = 128512; i < 128576; i++) {
  $(".smiley-picker").append("<button type='button' value='&#"+i+"' class='smiley'>&#" + i + "</button>");
}
for (i = 128581; i < 128591; i++) {
  $(".smiley-picker").append("<button type='button' value='&#"+i+"' class='smiley'>&#" + i + "</button>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and pretty good working in fiddle (look at fiddle below)

Comment: there you have `smiley` instead of `smiley-button` like you said. anyway it works now