# jQuery click event on button doesn't assign the value to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm coding a calculator and I'm trying to get the "." that is the value assigned to a button. When click on the button I want to put the value of the button in a variable and then I show it in the content of a `div`.

For numbers I retrieve the result but for "." not happen.

Here is the link to my codepen work: [javascript calculator][1]

```
$('button').click(function(){
    input = $(this).val();

    if (!isNaN(eval(input)) || input === "."){
      console.log("input: "+input);
      current += input;
      log = current;
      result += input;
    $("#answer").text(current);
    $("#history").text(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: you can get value from input element only,

Comment: a button usually doesn't have a value

Comment: missing codepen link

Comment: buttons don't have values

Comment: A button can absolutely have a `value` attribute, and here's how to get it using jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487056/retrieve-button-value-with-jquery

Comment: @Pierre-LoupPagniez you should read: .attr("value") it can have an attribute with the word "value" but that doesn't mean the button value can be called with .val(), go read the answer to the link you posted

Comment: Where did I say the button value could be called with `.val()`? I only said that `value` is a valid attribute for the tag `button`.

Comment: @zerohero https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-value

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p9g5tvsc/1/ - seems fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value is only associated with input elements, So `.val()` will not give you the value attribute of button. But since a `button value` is an `attribute` you need to use the `.attr()` method in jquery. This should do it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('button').click(function(){
    input = $(this).attr("value")

    if (input === "." || !isNaN(eval(input))){
      console.log("input: "+input);
      current += input;
      log = current;
      result += input;
    $("#answer").text(current);
    $("#history").text(result);
    }
});
</script>
```

```js
$('button').click(function(){
        var input = $(this).attr("value")
    
        if ( input === "." || !isNaN(eval(input))){
          console.log("input: "+input);
          
        }
  });

 
It is failing for you because when you test `!isNan(eval(input))` where `input = "."` your code breaks. change it to `if ( input === "." || !isNaN(eval(input))){`
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value = ".">Hello</button>
```

Comment: I changed with attr.("value") but it still doesn't works. I see that it doesn't enter the if statement because i put a console.log(input) inside the if and it doesn't return any.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** Since `button` element is not of type `input` you will not be able to get its value by just using `.val()` on the element.

**Solution:**
 Use `.attr` on the button to get the data in the `value` attribute

```
 input = $(this).attr('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: to not ruin your journey while learning js, I considered to just fix what you are asking, not to correct everything that can go wrong ;)*

consider this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hakeero/cw82r1se/3/

this is what I've ended up writing and making the program 'display' both numbers and the floating point in the textbox.

```
    $('button').click(function(){
    input = $(this).text();

    if (input || input === "."){
      console.log("input: "+input);
      current += input;
      log = current;
      result += input;
    $("#answer").text(current);
    $("#history").text(result);

    }
});
```

notes about the solution:

1- for simplicity, I've only added buttons for just 1 and 2.

2- to properly read the button text, you need to simply use the jquery method `text()`

```
input = $(this).text();
```

3- I've skipped to call `eval` on every input in your original code, since it will not work if you try to evaluate the floating point `.`, will leave it to you to think about another fix ;)

hope this helps.