# Javascript $(var).html(data); not working

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm currently using javascript to try and update a page with ajax. however, using .html to update the page with the parameter i pass in ends with no resulting changes. The html page is a grid of buttons and i'm trying to update the button being right clicked with the 'flaggedcell' img. I can sucessfully log the data that i'm trying to replace, however, in the line right below that, the .html function isnt doing anything.

Javascript:

```js
$(function() {
  console.log("Page is ready");
  $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Right click. Prevent context menu from showing.")
  });

  $(document).on("mousedown", ".game-button", function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
      case 1:
        var buttonNumber = $(this).val();
        console.log("Button number " + buttonNumber + " was left clicked");
        break;
      case 2:
        alert('Middle mouse button is pressed');
        break;
      case 3:
        event.preventDefault();
        var buttonNumber = $(this).val();
        console.log("Button Number " + buttonNumber + " was right clicked");
        doFlag(buttonNumber);
        break;
      default:
        alert('Nothing');
    }
  });
});

function doFlag(buttonNumber) {
  $.ajax({
    datatype: "json",
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/grid/flag',
    data: {
      "cellNumber": buttonNumber
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // this data logs succesfully
      console.log(data);
      //this changes nothing
      $("#" + buttonNumber).html(data);
    }
  })
}
```

data html:

```
@model MinesweeperASP.NET.Models.Cell
@{
    //store image names in an array for more efficient code.
    string[] imageNames = { "UnoenedCell.png", "green.png", "bomb.png", "FlaggedCell.png" };
    int i = 0;
}
 
@if (!Model.isVisited && Model.isFlagged)
{
    i = 3;
}


<button class="game-button" type="submit" value="@Model.rowNumber,@Model.colNumber" name="cellNumber" asp-controller="Grid" asp-action="HandleLeftClick">
    <img class="game-button-image" src="~/img/@imageNames[i]" />
    <div class="button-label">
        @Model.rowNumber
        ,
        @Model.colNumber
    </div>
</button>
```

Developer tools output:

```
Page is ready
site.js?v=yEzTfLHBcae6F8YYH3SeJjYAxKx_gxgY8BqS9gC2o5c:24 Button Number 0,1 was right clicked
site.js?v=yEzTfLHBcae6F8YYH3SeJjYAxKx_gxgY8BqS9gC2o5c:42  


<button class="game-button" type="submit" value="0,1" name="cellNumber" formaction="/Grid/HandleLeftClick">
    <img class="game-button-image" src="/img/FlaggedCell.png" />
    <div class="button-label">
        0
        ,
        1
    </div>
</button>


site.js?v=yEzTfLHBcae6F8YYH3SeJjYAxKx_gxgY8BqS9gC2o5c:5 Right click. Prevent context menu from showing.
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: `.bind()` has been long deprecated on jQuery. Use `.on()` instead.

Comment: This might apply to your code (not clear without seeing the actual markup): [Retrieve Button value with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487056/retrieve-button-value-with-jquery)

Comment: `$("#" + buttonNumber).html(data)` - There is a button with that id? -> Add the relevant markup to make this a [mcve]

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Your button is not having id attribute. Add the id attribute and check it.