# So i want to extract the value of these buttons from my code how should i do it

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Calculator</h5>
      <p class="card-text"><h1 id="disp">0</h1></p>
      <div id="btns">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-num="1">1</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-num="2">2</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-num="3">3</a><br><br>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-num="4">4</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-num="5">5</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-num="6">6</a><br><br>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-num="7">7</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-num="8">8</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-num="9">9</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to give each a distinct identifier and then use jquery with element.val() as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487056/retrieve-button-value-with-jquery). But these aren't buttons, they're images.

Comment: first you need to add id on button then you can start for loop.

Comment: These are not buttons but links. Hence, there's no value (attribute) to extract.
What you can do for example with jQuery is:
`jQuery('a').each(function(){
alert(jQuery(this).text()); // or:
alert(jQuery(this).data('num'));
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing this jquery code

```
$('.btn').click((e) => {
  var x = $(e.target).data('num');
  console.log(x)
   // this replaces text on h1
   $('#disp').text(x);
})
```